# Guidance for the background, Please design

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to place two boxes next to the recycle view. One blue box with text "working" and one red box with text "not working". It is to tell the user which way to swipe the item either left or right. Is this possible, I am struggling even to rotate the text and display it like I want.

[image: what I have currently]

I have tried designing a custom xml, but no luck. its just for gradient stuff. which I don't want.

[image: what I need]

Please see the attached images of what I want.

Comment: How if you create a image working and not working (with vertical text) and then use horizontal linearlayout to show working image - RecyclerView - Not working image ?

Comment: Genius i will try this